# Store cookie information with express-rate-limit

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, rate-limiting

Is there a way by which I can store user cookies (jwt) in my mongodb database with express-rate-limit and rate-limit-mongo packages?

Code that I am currently using :

```
var limiter = new RateLimit({
  store: new MongoStore({
     uri: process.env.MONGO_URI,
     expireTimeMs: 60 * 1000 * 60,
  }),
  max: 150,
  windowMs: 10 * 60 * 1000,
  message: "Too many requests in a short duration, IP Banned for an hour.",
});
```

I want to know the jwt cookie (if it exists) associated with the request too somehow so that I can know who the culprit was.

Basically, how can I access the request object and store it in the rate limiting database

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with the onLimitReached function available in express-rate-limit like so:

```
var queslimiter = new RateLimit({
  store: new MongoStore({
    uri: process.env.MONGO_URI,
    expireTimeMs: 60 * 1000 * 60,
    collectionName: "ansForce",
  }),
  max: 30,
  message: "Too many requests in a short duration, IP Banned for an hour.",
  onLimitReached: async function (req, res) {
    try {
      const blacklist = new Blacklist({
        team: req.cookies.team,
      });
      try {
        const bad = await blacklist.save();
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    } catch (e) {}
  },
});
```